# Why doesn't "wp db cli" enable tab completion?

Tags: wp-cli

I would like to use tab completion when using the MySQL REPL accessed by running `wp db cli`. However it doesn't seem to work, even though my `~/.my.cnf` file contains this content:

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

If I use the `mysql` command directly, tab completion does work.

Running `wp db cli --defaults` doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: As a workaround, type `\#` and press enter in the MySQL REPL. That should enable tab completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP-CLI [turns it off by default](https://github.com/wp-cli/db-command/blob/86d2d3e907f092224063ca4dfbe62f033677c2c8/src/DB_Command.php#L193) in order to [improve performance](https://github.com/wp-cli/db-command/commit/48dc5d1273515afa3319e56ebe50e51079c48a85).

You can manually enable it by running `wp db cli --auto-rehash`. That's not very convenient, though, so a better way is to add it to [your custom configuration file](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/references/config/):

```
# Global parameters: https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/#global-parameters
path: public_html/wordpress

# DB parameters
db cli:
  auto-rehash: 1
```